# Criar Views no banco de dados a partir de função

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples onde vai ser preciso criar uma views no PostgreSQL através de função em Python. Até então parece um código simples, mas o que fiz ele não cria a `views` no banco de dados e também não apresenta erro para meu desespero.

A função é:

```
 def cria_view(self):
    cursor = self.connectBanco()    
     sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW espacial.teste AS SELECT *FROM espacial.fx_pedestre;"

     cursor.execute(sql)
```

Aqui chamo o método:

```
instancia_sql.cria_view()
```

Com esse mesmo SQL crio a view pelo Query do Postgresql, mas pela função em Python não cria, mas também não dá erro. Alguém sabe porque? Estou errando alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez seja necessário usar o método [`MySQLConnection.commit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) para confirmar a transação atual e salvar as alterações.

```
conexao = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd  = "pass", db = "dbname")
cursor = self.connectBanco()    

sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW espacial.teste AS SELECT * FROM espacial.fx_pedestre;"
cursor.execute(sql)

conexao.commit()
```

**Nota**: Assumindo que a função `self.connectBanco` retorna um objeto [`cursor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-cursor.html), não é possível usar `cursor.commit()`, se você preferir alterar isso, na função `self.connectBanco` faça algo assim:

```
def connectBanco(self):
    conexao = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", ...)

    # Códigos...
    return conexao
```

No método `cria_view` você pode fazer assim:

```
def cria_view(self):
    conexao = self.connectBanco()
    cursor  = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW espacial.teste AS SELECT * FROM espacial.fx_pedestre;"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    conexao.commit()
```

Comment: Valeu stderr, Faltava o commit mesmo. Erro de principiante, e olha que passei um tempão pesquisando e não lembrei que estava alterando a estrutura do banco.